# How do you get average RTT of a ping to a certain DNS in Linux using a Bash Script?

Tags: linux, bash

When I write this command in the terminal of a Linux:

```
ping -c 10 8.8.4.4
```

I get the following response:

```
PING 8.8.4.4 (8.8.4.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=44.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=44.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=44.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=44.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=5 ttl=128 time=44.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=6 ttl=128 time=43.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=7 ttl=128 time=44.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=8 ttl=128 time=43.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=9 ttl=128 time=43.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=10 ttl=128 time=43.7 ms

--- 8.8.4.4 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9015ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 43.473/44.001/44.375/0.252 ms
```

I would like to know how I can write a bash script that would automatically get me the RTT avg number in the following format: "avg RTT is 44.001"

What's a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

steps:

1- do the actual ping: ping -c 10 8.8.4.4

2- get the last line (since the average in the last line) using tail -1, this way it does not matter how much you ping.

3- split the last line by spaces, the forth section is where the average is.

4- split the section and get the actual average.

you can chain the steps in one command in bash using pipes
final result:

```
ping -c 10 8.8.4.4 | tail -1| awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2
```

Comment: The problem here is that it returns all the values of the fourth field, while I only need the second value of that field. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: forgot to add the last step,  updated the answer

Comment: Thanks, that worked! How does the "cut -d '/' -f 2" line exactly work?

Comment: -d is the delimiter
-f is what you are trying to print
https://www.programming-books.io/essential/bash/cut-command-4fb03c5aa2144c39b7a24fbe0793a8f9